# MySQL multiples SUM() functions inside one query as fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I'm trying to get each of the following sums as fields, I'm only getting the outer one, the other two return undefined index.

How do I put them outside as fields?

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(amount) AS income
    FROM transaction 
    WHERE 
    type = '1' && state = 'a') 

- (SELECT SUM(amount) AS expense 
    FROM transaction 
    WHERE 
    type = '2' && state = 'a') 
    AS balance
```

Balance works, but for income and expense I get undefined index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0
           END) as income,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = '2' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0
           END) as balance
FROM transaction;
```

If you still want the difference, then you need to repeat the logic:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0
           END) as income,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = '2' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0
           END) as expense,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = '2' AND state = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) 
       ) as balance
FROM transaction;
```

EDIT:

Actually, it is better to factor out the common conditions into a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as income,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = '2' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as expense,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = '2' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) 
       ) as balance
FROM transaction
WHERE state = 'a' AND type IN ('1', '2');
```

This can take advantage of an index on `transaction(state, type, amount)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and `sum` to get each result:

```
select sum(case when `type` = '1' then `amount` else 0 end) as `income`
     , sum(case when `type` = '2' then `amount` else 0 end) as `expense `
     , sum((case when `type` = '2' then -1 else 1 end) * `amount`) as `difference`
from `transaction`
where `type` in ('1', '2')
where `state` = 'a'
```

Comment: Why did you remove that statement where you were saying I shouldn't use  "&&", I wanted to ask why.

Comment: @Relm: Because I was mistaken – I guess only MySQL permits such syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `income` and `expense` since they are only defined in their respective subqueries and not in the top level query, which only has one field - the difference between them. I'd put in a subquery, and then select them both and the difference between them. To make this query easier and remove the need for subqueries, you can emulate the behavior of two different `where` clauses by extracting the different conditions to `case` expressions in the `sum`'s arguments:

```
SELECT income, expense, income - expense AS balance
FROM   (SELECT SUM(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN amount ELSE NULL) AS income,
               SUM(CASE type WHEN 2 THEN amount ELSE NULL) AS expense,
        FROM   `transaction`
        WHERE  state = 'a') t
```

Comment: t? What is "t" and where is being used?

Comment: @Relm `t` is a table-alias for the subquery. It's not used directly, but MySQL (and several other relational databases) mandate having it. Without it, you'd get an error like "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias".